# Linq to Entities - Get list of all unique related entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, sql-server-2012-express

asp.net mvc 4, Entity Framework 5, SQL Server 2012 Express, Code First

I have a Place model:

```
public virtual int PlaceID { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

and a related Tag model:

```
public virtual int TagID { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual string NamePlural { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Place> Places { get; set; }
```

they have a many to many relationship.

I have a List places - and I would like to create a List tags - populated with every (unique) tag associated with every place in 'places'.

For example, one place might have 'restaurant' and 'pub' tag, another 'pub' and 'bar', and another 'shop' and 'cafe'.

I would like the List to contain one of each of the tags with these names:
Bar, Cafe, Restaurant, Pub, Shop

How can I do this in Linq?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the tag objects or just the name of tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the unique tag names you can do:

```
places.SelectMany(x => x.Tags).Select(x => x.Name).Distinct()
```

if the two instances of the same tag are the same object then you can just do

```
places.SelectMany(x => x.Tags).Distinct();
```

if they are different objects then you can do

```
places.SelectMany(x => x.Tags).GroupBy(x => x.TagId).Select(g => g.First());
```

UPDATE after new comment.

Add `ToList()` to then end to convert the result into a list.

```
places.SelectMany(x => x.Tags).Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList();
places.SelectMany(x => x.Tags).Distinct().ToList();
places.SelectMany(x => x.Tags).GroupBy(x => x.TagId).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks - getting this error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d__81`1[myapp.Models.Tag]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[myapp.Models.Tag]'.